# Only one function is working either Delete from DB or Delete from Server

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller

I am trying to Delete Images of a Post, But only one action is performing which I put First. Either Delete from DB  or Delete from Folder / Server.

Both Action Works Fine but only One Which i Put First.

Note: I am call this Controller function through Ajax Get Request from Blade/View

```
public function deletePermanently(){
    $id = Input::get('id');
    Photo::where('post_id',$id)->delete();
    $obj = Post::with(['pictures'])->find($id);
    $filePath = public_path().'/upload/';
    if(count($obj->pictures) > 0){
        foreach($obj->pictures as $photo){
            if(file_exists($filePath.$photo->name)){                                       
                unlink($filePath.$photo->name);                    
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting Delete from both DB and Folder / Server at once

Comment: Because of delete action is executed here `Photo::where('post_id',$id)->delete();` which means that that `id` isn't anymore in the database

Comment: Absolutely Right thats my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were deleting the pictures in the database without taking the pictures I have taken the `pictures` before the delete action is executed.

```
 Photo::where('post_id',$id)->delete();
 $obj = Post::with(['pictures'])->find($id);
```

I have swapped the order of these lines

```
 $obj = Post::with(['pictures'])->find($id);
 Photo::where('post_id',$id)->delete();
```

Your final code should look like this

```
public function deletePermanently(){
$id = Input::get('id');
$obj = Post::with(['pictures'])->find($id);
Photo::where('post_id',$id)->delete();
$filePath = public_path().'/upload/';
if(count($obj->pictures) > 0){
    foreach($obj->pictures as $photo){
        if(file_exists($filePath.$photo->name)){                                       
            unlink($filePath.$photo->name);                    
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must delete the image and then delete the record. If you delete the record you can't find the record again to delete the image. So do something like this:

```
public function deletePermanently(){
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $obj = Post::with(['pictures'])->find($id);
    $filePath = public_path().'/upload/';
    if(count($obj->pictures) > 0){
        foreach($obj->pictures as $photo){
            if(file_exists($filePath.$photo->name)){                                       
                unlink($filePath.$photo->name);                    
            }

        }
    }
    Photo::where('post_id',$id)->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::delete('file.jpg');
```